# weird white outline on dropdown menu in unity

Tags: unity, unity-ui

I have a dropdown and whenever I click it, this happens:

[image: White lines in dropdown]

How do I get rid of these outlines?

It seems to be caused by the dropdown object that gets spawned not letting you set the background color for it — so how do I do that?